# Cron and Crouton (Chromebox)

Tags: python-2.7, cron, chromebook

I can't get cron jobs to run properly on my ASUS Chromebox, which is running Crouton. I have followed [these](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Setting-Up-Cron-Job) instructions.

- I've edited /etc/rc.local
- I've added the cron job to /etc/crontab
- When I run crontab -l as root, I see the cron job
- The script works when I run it from the terminal

The cron job is this: 30 2 * * * /home/name/daily.py

Answer (score 0):

Can't be certain with the info provided, but this could be as simple as the `PATH` not being set correctly for *cron*. Keep in mind, *cron* doesn't source dotfiles like `.bashrc`, so it won't have all the settings that your shell has. Just set the `PATH` in `/etc/crontab` before defining the individual cronjob.